# Do-While Loop with Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, do-while

Can a do-while loop have multiple conditions?  If so, I can't figure out why the code below is failing on all but the first condition.

Functions used...

```
function gcf($a,$b) {
$a = abs($a); $b = abs($b);
if( $a < $b) list($b,$a) = Array($a,$b);
if( $b == 0) return $a;
$r = $a % $b;
while($r > 0) {
    $a = $b;
    $b = $r;
    $r = $a % $b;
}
return $b;
}


function factors($n){
$factors_array = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= sqrt(abs($n)); $x++)
{
    if ($n % $x == 0)
    {
        $z = $n/$x; 
        array_push($factors_array, $x, $z);
    }
}
return $factors_array;
}
```

Code...

```
$a = $b;

do{
    $a = mt_rand(8, 100);
    $a_factors_array = factors($a);

    $b = mt_rand(8, 100);
    $b_factors_array = factors($b);

} while ($a == $b && count($a_factors_array) < 4 && count($b_factors_array) < 4 && gcf($a, $b) == 1);

echo $a . '<br>';
echo $b . '<br>';

echo count($a_factors_array) . '<br>';
echo count($b_factors_array) . '<br>';

echo gcf($a, $b) . '<br>';
```

I keep getting numbers for $a and $b that have less than 4 factors and have a GCF of 1.  Any ideas?

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa.  I think `while ($a == $b &&` might be wrong.  I think you meant `while ($a == $b || (otherstuff));`.  Otherwise, you'll stop after the first pass where A <> B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `||` instead of `&&`. You want to repeat the loop as long as *any* one of your conditions is met. Currently the loop is only repeated if *all* of the conditions are met.

Comment: Gahhh!!!  Right || instead of &&.  Do-while loops are kind of logically backward from regular while loops.  Thanks.

Comment: You can reverse each of the conditions and use `&&`. For instance `$check = $a != $b && (count($a_factors_array) >= 4) ...;`. Then, in the loop write `while ($check === false)`. So instead of writing `while any check fails` you are writing` while not all checks are okay`. That makes it a little easier to read. And you can do it without the extra variable: just put the entire condition in extra parentheses and add `===false` after that. But I think it makes it even more readable to use an extra variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an ANDs where you meant an ORs:

```
do{
    $a = mt_rand(8, 100);
    $a_factors_array = factors($a);

    $b = mt_rand(8, 100);
    $b_factors_array = factors($b);

} while ($a == $b || count($a_factors_array) < 4 || count($b_factors_array) < 4 || gcf($a, $b) == 1);
```

With your way, the `while` stops if `$a !== $b` which is probably not what you want.