# PHP do while with multiple while conditions

Tags: while-loop, multiple-conditions

I'm hoping somone might be able to help me here. I've had a look and found someone who has had he same issue:
[Do-While Loop with Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709057/do-while-loop-with-multiple-conditions)

However I've checked and cannot see where i'm going wrong

Here's my code:

```
$x=0;
$y=0;
do {
$x = rand(0,5);
$y++;
} while ($x!=5 || $y<=5);
```

and so I was expecting the following: Either the code to stop when X was not == 5 OR y was more than 5. However the result i got was x=5 and y=>5

To put the theory to the test i changed my code to:

```
$x=0;
$y=0;
echo'<br />--x-y';
do {
    $x = rand(0,5);
    $y++;
    echo'<br />--'.$x.'-'.$y;
    if($y>5)
        echo"-I should finish here";
} while ($x!==5 || $y<=5);
echo "<br />x=".$x;
echo "<br />y=".$y;
```

and in one instance i ended up with :

```
--x-y
--5-1
--3-2
--4-3
--4-4
--2-5
--4-6-I should finish here
--1-7-I should finish here
--3-8-I should finish here
--3-9-I should finish here
--3-10-I should finish here
--3-11-I should finish here
--5-12-I should finish here
x=5
y=12
```

Any suggestions as to where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to stop when `(X = 5 or Y > 5)`. The condition inside while is for continuing, so you have to inverse the condition to: `(X != 5 AND Y <= 5)`

[De Morgan Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Just on final question of the back of this: How can i check if a variable isset and what the value or the variable IE:
while(!isset($json->meta->code) AND $json->meta->code!=200 AND $retires!=3)
if $json->meta->code is not set i get an error :(

Comment: It's okay I assigned $json->meta->code to a variable inside the do loop and checking this value instead :)